# viewmodels postValue called from dialog doesn't change UI in MainActivity

Tags: android, mvvm, android-viewmodel, mutablelivedata

I am starting off with my ViewModel (sry for mixing Kotlin with Java)

```kotlin
class MainViewModel : ViewModel() {
    val textViewIP: MutableLiveData<String> = MutableLiveData()
}
```

In my DialogFragment, I change the MutableLiveData when pressing the positive button. I tried postValue and setValue.

```kotlin
private fun positiveButtonClicked() {
    prefManager.ip = editTextIP.text.toString().trim()
    mainViewModel.textViewIP.postValue(prefManager.ip)
    dismiss()
}
```

This is what I do in my MainActivity where I want to change the value immediately. Changing and updating the value of the UI inside MainActivity works. But when I change the value from my DialogFragment, the UI is not updated. I have to restart the app. I am sure that I am missing something. Do I need Observers or something? If so, how does it work in my case?

```java
private MainViewModel mainViewModel;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ActivityMainBinding activityMainBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);
    mainViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(MainViewModel.class);
    activityMainBinding.setViewmodel(mainViewModel);
    activityMainBinding.setLifecycleOwner(this);
    ...
    mainViewModel.getTextViewIP().setValue(prefManager.getIp());
}
```

```xml
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewIP"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@{viewmodel.textViewIP}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The lifecycle in **DilogFragment** should be same lifecycle in **MainActivity** and when you call **setLifecyleOwner()** pass **MainActivity** lifecycle in both activity and **DialogFragment**

Comment: Can you give me some code? I don't quite understand how I can setLifecyleOwner inside my DialogFragment.